# Remove a plugin from the Gutenberg sidebar

Tags: block-editor

How do you remove a Gutenberg plugin?

I want to disable a plugin added by my parent theme (Genesis). I am familiar with removing blocks and editor panels, but I can't find a way to deregister a plugin.

Here is the code used to register the plugin:

```
registerPlugin( 'genesis-sidebar', { render, icon: <GenesisIconSmall /> } );
```

Comment: I emptied the JS file to disable the plugin. It's a poor practice but necessary with Gutenberg.